# How to correctly receive responses from the ARP protocol

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy, arp

I want to make a small script for monitoring the local network for the presence of devices in it.
I am using `ARP protocol` `request and response`, here is my code:

```
import time
import scapy.all as scapy
import argparse
import pandas as pd


def get_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--target', '-t', dest='target', help='Target IP / IP range.')
    option = parser.parse_args()
    return option


def scan(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast / arp_request
    answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=3, verbose=False)[0]

    clients_list = []
    for element in answered_list:
        clients_dict = {'ip': element[1].psrc, 'mac': element[1].hwsrc}
        clients_list.append(clients_dict)
    return clients_list


opt = get_arguments()
while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    scan_result = pd.DataFrame(scan(opt.target))
    print(scan_result)
```

In principle, everything works, but there is one big problem in my opinion. Somehow, the answer is returned to me that there are fewer connected devices on the network than in reality. see picture.

[image]

As you can see, the first `two answers` show me the real picture of what is happening, i.e. I see all `six devices` (highlighted in `red`), but then an absolutely unknown situation happens to me, for some reason there are `more or less devices`, some kind of random answer.

Could you tell me please, Is this problem caused by the peculiarities of the `ARP protocol`? Or is there some `error in the code`?

Would you mind telling me how can improve this code or do something differentl?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The other question is what are the devices that are only intermittently responding? Your code could be correct (and, eyeballing it, looks to be so), but it's only one part of the equation. Does your result change if you make the call to  `sleep`  longer? shorter?

Comment: @Elliot, What exactly interests you about devices? Models? Yes, the code is correct, copy and run, substituting the correct attribute. If you set a lower download time, then the result will not change, I have not tried it with a large interval, I'll try.

Comment: l don't care so much about the devices themselves, but it's a natural question to ask when the rest of the code looks right. If you really want to know what's going on with the devices and why they don't always respond to ARP it's more likely to be found in their implementation. (Though, there being 1 Raspberry Pi that always responds, and two that don't may throw a wrench into that search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having studied the `scapy` [documentation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) better, I found that can use the `retry` parameter in `scapy.srp`, and now my line in the code looks like this:

```
answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=2, retry=-2 verbose=False)[0]
```

Thus, now all devices located on the local network respond to me and are correctly displayed.